# ASP.NET MVC Square Bracket Collection Model Binding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, collections, model-binding, jquery-select2

ASP.NET MVC's collection model binding requires square bracket indices in `<input />` name attributes for collection models to be bound correctly, e.g. `<input name="Lines[0].Name" />` with an action like:

```
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<MyInputModel> Lines) {
    // ...
}
```

However, periods and square brackets in name attributes are a [known issue](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/02/11/38013/) for certain jQuery plugins, including the [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) list selector that I am using.

Since I don't want to hack on Select2, how can I tell ASP.NET MVC to use something like periods or underscores instead of square brackets to delimit collection indices, e.g. `<input name="Lines.0.Name" />`?

---

**Note:** I am using this [collection model binding technique](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-model-binding-for-a-collection.aspx) to generate non-sequential `Guid` indices, so am already declaring a custom `HtmlFieldPrefixScope`.

---

**Update:** I solved this by hacking the custom scroll/resize event names in Select2 events that pass invalid `[` or `]` characters to `bind`/`unbind` jQuery methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Create(List<MyInputModel> Lines) {
    // ...
}

<input name="Lines[0].Name" />
```

make sure input name **same as list name** and **index start with 0**.

ohh sorry i miss understand. try this way.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   var name = string.Format("Lines[{0}].name", i);
   <input type="text" name="@name" value="@item.name" />
}
```

Comment: This does not address my question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realy need a list of entities? Because if not, and a list of strings will be enough, you could skip brackets with indexes: [like here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Comment: Each item has multiple attributes. The link you provided also uses square brackets to index items.

Comment: Yes, if items has several attributes(not just 'Name') you should use brackets. That's why I ask you question. But in case just 'name' property according to the link above you could write smth like: <input type="text" name="Names" value="Name1" />
<input type="text" name="Names" value="Name2" />  But as I understood you , it's not a solution for you...Hope, you'll find another one.

Answer (score 0):

You can can't customize the DefaultModelBinder to achieve that. But you could use a custom `FormValueProvider` that will convert the incoming prefix format from `List.0.Name` into `List[0].Name` and return value for that.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I might have to write a custom collection model binder. Can you point me in the right direction on how to do this? Some sample code would go a long way.

Comment: Creating a custom collection model binder is a complex job you can understand that when you see the source code of the DefaultModelBinder and some of the methods are internals or private making our life complex.

Comment: Fixed this by hacking at Select2. Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can change your selectors to use the 'id' attribute instead of the 'name' one. If so, the collections binding in MVC will still work, and you'll have jquery safe values in the id attributes that you can use with Select2:

```
@for(int i=0; i<Lines.Count; i++) {
    <input name="@Html.FieldNameFor(m=>m.Name)" id="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.Name)" />
}
```